# insert a group of rows in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, grouped-table

So Im working on an Excel sheet for a colleague of mine, and what I would like to know is. 
Is there any way where you can insert a copy of the grouped rows 3 to 9 below it? Normally i would make a VBA to do it, however the person im making this for is VERY not-technical so if there is any way of doing it without using VBA would be very great[image]

I am aware that its a long shot, but any help as to how i can copy and paste the 7 rows grouped from G and with the MATCH/INDEX formular in H is very much appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood right. Do you want to copy and paste cells "G3" to "G9" into "H3" to "H9" or do you want to copy the hole rows?

Comment: You could manually select rows 3 to 9 and then insert them in row 10. It's annoying, but at least is 100% human way. No VBA skills required at all.

Comment: @Mikkel Astrup can you gìve us an example of that do you want ?